Move .NET Core 3.1 project to Azure
I have a .NET Core project which is:
<TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>

This project is currently hosted in Azure under:
 Runtime Stack => Dotnetcore

I try to move this site under different subscription, so I need to create a new web app, I don't see
Runtime Stack - Dotnetcore 

anymore to choose; I can only choose from this list:
 ASP.NET V3.5
 ASP.NET V4.8
 ASP.NET V6
 ASP.NET V8

Which one I can choose? Or is the only way is to update my project?
I appreciate any feedback.

.NET Core 3.1 reached end of life years ago. You need to upgrade the code base to .NET 8 before moving on.

@LexLi thank will plan that.

@LexLi, you can consider posting your comment as an answer. Your suggestion that upgrading the app to the supported .NET versions should be the best answer for this question.

I created sample Asp. net core 3.1 application and deployed to the Azure Web App service.
It Good to update your app .net 3.1 version to .net 8 as @LexLi suggested.
If you want to continue with .net 3.1 version deploy your app to Azure Web app service through Visual Studio.
I selected my project -> Right Click -> Publish -> Azure -> Azure App service (Windows) -> Create new.




After Create new I filled the necessary details and clicked the Create button.

I selected the newly created web app and clicked Finish button.

It is successfully published to Azure as shown below.

You can check Runtime Stack - Dotnetcore in Overview page of Azure Web app.

Azure Web App Output:


@Alma Please check if the solution above helped you. Let me know if there's anything else I can assist with.
